# Re-compiling a DOS executable to run on Windows?

Tags: windows, compilation, dos, executable

Before I ask my question, I'd just like to state that I'm new to this site, and this is my first post, so don't beat me up too much! ;)

Okay, so my problem is this: I want to take an already made DOS executable and re-compile (is that a word?) it to run on modern Windows systems instead of giving me the "this app can't run on your PC" dialog.

Now, please do not say "just use DOSBox." There is a specific reason I want to do this the way I said it.

If you do know a way that this would be possible, then please notify me!

Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, do you have the source code?

Comment: Sorry, no. That's my problem. I've lost the source a ways back, and all I have left is the old DOS .exe

Comment: There is no reasonable way to go from a DOS .exe to a Windows executable.  In principle you could run it through a disassembler and reverse engineer it, but it would almost always be easier and faster to code the new application from scratch.

Comment: (There might be emulators other than DOSBox that would be more suitable for your needs, but I'm not aware of any, and that question would be off-topic here.)